Integral of $e^{\frac{-1}{x(1-x)}}$
The function $e^{\frac{-1}{x(1-x)}}$ is a smooth positive function supported on the compact set $[0,1]$.
What is its integral? (According to WolframAlpha, it's approximately 0.007, but I was hoping for a more 'theoretical' understanding.)

Here are some results for other bump functions that may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145015/evaluate-definite-integral-int-11-exp1-x2-1-dx https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585768/how-to-integrate-the-bump-functions-i-e-int-abe-frac1x-a-frac1x

The solution was given by @Harry Peter here.
Make $a=0$ and $b=1$ and then
$$\int_0^1 e^{\frac{-1}{x(1-x)}}\,dx=\frac{2 }{e^2}\,\big(K_1(2)-K_0(2)\Big)$$ which is $0.00702986$ as given by Wolfram Alpha.
