# Evaluate integral $\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 \exp(\frac{1}{x^2-1}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate this integral?

$\int_{-1}^{1} x^2 \exp(\frac{1}{x^2-1}) dx$

If possible, I want any solution in elementary/non-elementary functions.

Many thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145015/97236) is a similar integral, maybe you can use the result there?

Comment: Beside numerical integration, I really do not see any closed form for this one.

Comment: In terms of the [*Meijer G-function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function), we have $I=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2G_{1,2}^{2,0}\bigg(1;\displaystyle{5/2\choose0,1}\bigg).$

Answer (score 1):

By substituting $\cosh^2t=\dfrac1{1-x^2}$ and exploiting the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the integrand, we finally

arrive at $I=2\Big[I_2(1)-I_4(1)\Big]$, where $I_k(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-a\cosh^2x}}{\cosh^kx}~dx.~$ Also, we notice that

$-I'_2(1)=I''_4(1)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-a\cosh^2x}~dx,~$ where the differentiation happens with regard to

the parameter *a*. Using the fact that $\cosh^2x=\dfrac{1+\cosh2x}2$ along with our [knowledge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196401)

of [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), we evaluate the last integral to equal $\dfrac12~K_0\bigg(\dfrac a2\bigg)~\exp\bigg(\!\!-\dfrac a2\bigg).$

Unfortunately, it would seem that the latter's first and second order anti-derivatives cannot

be expressed in terms of Bessel functions. $($I might be wrong, and I hope I am, but so far

I've had no luck in finding such a closed form for them$)$. However, not all is lost, since we

can always count on the [Meijer G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function) to come to our rescue. Thus, $$I=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2~G_{1,2}^{2,0}\bigg(1;\displaystyle{5/2\choose0,1}\bigg).$$ If someone could rewrite this last expression in terms of Bessel or [Struve functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function), I would

be very, very grateful.